# Transform and filter column - Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like to transform a CSV and then filter the result within Camel. For example with the given csv:

```
Product,Quantity
cheese,90
milk,100
milk,90
```

How would I transform the `Product` column to be `Proper` case and then filter the rows to only include the `Milk` category?

I have tried the following:

```
@Component
public class TransformMessage extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        DataFormat bindy =
                new BindyCsvDataFormat(com.model.Product.class);

        from("file:data/?fileName=products.csv&noop=true")
                .log("Message: ${body}")
                .transform(body().regexReplaceAll("milk", "Milk")) /* unsure on how to select a column to operate over */
                .filter() /* unsure on how to select a column to operate over */
                .unmarshal(bindy)
```

The current transform changes all text and doesn't operate over a single column as I intend.

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 1):

You need to think in terms of `EIPs` and likely uses a [splitter](https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html), a [filter](https://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html) and a [message translator](https://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html). With the first your unit of work will be the CVS row, with the second you can just process the items you need and with the third you will apply transformation required.